# Combine elasticsearch date range queries with null values

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use date range query like the following :

```
{
    "range" : {
        "deadline" : {
            "gte" : "2016-12-14",
        }
    }
}
```

My index contains empty values for deadline as well. I would like to get those null dated documents in search results along with the dates in range. How can I combine date range with "must_not" exist query in elastic 5.x

Comment: You mean to avoid null values within your date range ?

Comment: From my understanding, he wants the search to return either the one with date grater than 2016-12-14 or have no deadline date associated to the document.

Answer (score 26):

I think a *bool query* would do the trick.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "deadline": {
              "gte": "2016-12-14"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "deadline"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In Elasticsearch indexes *null* values don't exist, so we use the *exist query*. Using the missing query would been less verbose, but it's [deprecated since 2.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html).

I don't have enough information so my example runs in *query context*, but maybe *filter context* would be more convenient in this case.